# How to Validate CKEditor with bootstrapvalidation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, bootstrapvalidator

Using `CKEditor 4.5.6` with `bootstrapvalidator 0.5.2`

I followed example from website http://formvalidation.io/examples/ckeditor/ however couldn't make it validate.

Also getting JavaScript Console Error in Chrome Browser(Other Browser didn't check) as:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined

Above Error is displayed only on Form Submission. PHP Form loaded using `$.load(...)` and posted using `$.post(...)`

> Note:- I couldn't simulate error in JSFiddle. I want to validate
>   `CKEditor` using `bootstrapvalidator`

Added Full code in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nxxxbw90/4/

```js
var editor;
$(document).ready(function(){
 editor=CKEDITOR.replace('policyta', {
  removePlugins: 'sourcearea'
 });
  $('#setpolicyform').bootstrapValidator({
  message: 'This value is not valid',
        ignore: [':disabled'],
  feedbackIcons: {
   valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
   invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
   validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
  },
  fields: {
   policyta: {
    group: '.lnbrd',
    validators: {
     notEmpty: {
      message: 'The Guidelines is required and cannot be empty'
     },
     callback: {
      message: 'The Guidelines must be less than 50000 characters long',
      callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
       if (value === '') {
        return true;
       }
       var div  = $('<div/>').html(value).get(0),
        text = div.textContent || div.innerText;

       return text.length <= 50000;
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }).on('success.form.bv', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  var $form = $("#setpolicyform"), $url = $form.attr('action'); 
  $.post($url,$form.serialize()).done(function(dte){ 
   $("#policy-content").html(dte); 
   loadfunctions(); 
  });
 });
 editor.on('change', function(ev){
  $("#setpolicyform").bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'policyta');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="policy-content">
<form role="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="setpolicyform" id="setpolicyform">
 <div class='box-body pad'>
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="lnbrd">
  <textarea class="form-control textarea" name="policyta" id="policyta" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-footer clearfix">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="setpolicyformsubmitbtn">SAVE</button>
 </div>
 </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of mistakes in your approach.

1. you don't need to initiate `CKEditor` on textarea, bootstrapValidator will do it for you.
2. you need to `excluded: [':disabled'],` not `ignore: [':disabled'],`
3. `if (value === '') {return true;}` value check inside `callback` function you are using in bootstrapValidator, no need of it.

**Notes:**

1. formValidation and bootstrapValidator are two different plugins so one plugin code reference will not work in other plugin
2. you have to use `CKEditor` v4.2 or later (which you are already using)

Here is working validation code, `CKEditor` with `bootstrapvalidator`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#setpolicyform').bootstrapValidator({
      excluded: [':disabled'],
      feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
      },
      fields: {
        policyta: {
          group: '.lnbrd',
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'The Guidelines is required and cannot be empty'
            },
            callback: {
              message: 'The Guidelines must be less than 50000 characters long',
              callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                var div = $('<div/>').html(value).get(0),
                  text = div.textContent || div.innerText;
                return text.length <= 50000;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }).find('[name="policyta"]')
    .ckeditor()
    .editor
    .on('change', function() {
      $('#setpolicyform').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'policyta');
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ogs9L4hj/)

Comment: I made validation work like this https://jsfiddle.net/nxxxbw90/8/ but the Console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined` is still there. i don't know how to fix this Error.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help to you

You need to use below ckeditor version (i am not sure it working or not for later versions).

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.3/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.3/basic/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
```

and then after

```
.find('[name="policyta"]')
.ckeditor()
.editor
.on('change', function () {
    $('#yourformid').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'policyta');
});
```

or Use below code

```
CKEDITOR.instances.policyta.updateElement();
```

Comment: Have you checked second solution (CKEDITOR.instances.policyta.updateElement();) ?

Comment: Yes I did. No Changes :(