# How to embed CKEditor to our html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I try to embed ckeditor to my html page but i got a error like this (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined).How to fix this error or how to embed that in any another methods? 
Note:[Please put the code]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452994/how-to-validate-ckeditor-with-bootstrapvalidation

Comment: CKEditor is well-documented with a lot of examples. Read and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Simple sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor" name="editor" >content</textarea>
<script>

// This call can be placed at any point after the
// <textarea>, or inside a <head><script> in a
// window.onload event handler.

// Replace the <textarea id="editor"> with an CKEditor
// instance, using default configurations.

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );

</script>
```

Demo Local Screenshot:
[image]

And below is the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CKEditor</title>       
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="editor1"  name="editor1"></textarea>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Important : Dont use CDN it will throw undefined error, since it will look up for config.js etc. Download the source from this [CKEditor Dowload](http://ckeditor.com/download) and then refer your path to the ckeditor js and load the HTML. TADA :)

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thennarasan,I tried the above code but i got  the same error,Thank you for your response :)

Comment: can you please post the error? or you will solve it and post?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined ------ckeditor.js:303

Comment: @karthiguna : Are you using CDN link for CKEditor? If so it will throw undefined error. Request to [download](http://ckeditor.com/download) and refer. I tried in my local, it worked file. Refer the comment i will upload the screenshot that was working in my end. With the complete HTML.

Comment: thennarasan,Now its working thanks for your response :)